# issues with login as a superuser

Tags: command-line, login

i'm currently working on my Ubuntu 20.04 workstation, and i tried to start a shell session as a superuser using the command `su -` then it gives me a prompt asking for password, i'm 100% sure i entered the correct one but still telling me the authentication failed. it worked perfectly before using the same password but now refuse to letting me in.

Comment: The command is `sudo su -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command on ubuntu was `sudo su -` not only `su -`